# BizTalk Server - Unable to assign logon user/password for Instance ( Via PowerShell)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am trying to create BizTalk instance using PowerShell function CreateBizTalkInstance as found here ( all of them are same)

[sandroasp /
BizTalk-Server-Resources/PowerShell-scripts/adm-bts2020-Configure-Host-Host-Instances-and-Handlers/ConfigureBizTalkServerEnvAccordingHostAndHostInstancesBestPractices_BTS2020.ps1](https://github.com/sandroasp/BizTalk-Server-Resources/blob/master/PowerShell-scripts/adm-bts2020-Configure-Host-Host-Instances-and-Handlers/ConfigureBizTalkServerEnvAccordingHostAndHostInstancesBestPractices_BTS2020.ps1) (github.com)

[BizTalk Server Best Practices: Create and Configure BizTalk Server Host and Host Instances](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19701.biztalk-server-best-practices-create-and-configure-biztalk-server-host-and-host-instances.aspx) (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/)

```
# Function to Create Host Instance
function CreateBizTalkHostInstance([string]$hostName, [string]$serverName, [string]$username, [string]$password)
{
    try
    {
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objServerHost = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_ServerHost").CreateInstance()
 
        $objServerHost["HostName"] = $hostName
        $objServerHost["ServerName"] = $serverName
        $objServerHost.Map()
 
        [System.Management.ManagementObject]$objHostInstance = ([WmiClass]"root/MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_HostInstance").CreateInstance()
 
        $name = "Microsoft BizTalk Server " + $hostName + " " + $serverName
        $objHostInstance["Name"] = $name
        write-host "$username : $Password"
        $objHostInstance.Install($username, $password,$true)
 
        Write-Host "HostInstance $hostName was mapped and installed successfully. Mapping created between Host: $hostName and Server: $serverName);" -Fore DarkGreen
        $LogFile.writeline("HostInstance $hostName was mapped and installed successfully. Mapping created between Host: $hostName and Server: $serverName);")
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
    {
        if ($_.Exception.Message.Contains("Another object with the same key properties already exists.") -eq $true)
        {
            Write-Host "$hostName host instance can't be created because another object with the same key properties already exists." -Fore DarkRed
            $LogFile.writeline("$hostName host instance can't be created because another object with the same key properties already exists.")
        }
        else{
            write-Error "$hostName host instance on server $Server could not be created: $_.Exception.ToString()"
            $LogFile.writeline("$hostName host instance on server $Server could not be created: $_.Exception.ToString()")
        }
    }
}
```

It creates the host instance successfully, however it doesn't assign passed username  password for login, and shows the instance is not configured

[image: HostInstance as shows here (Removed hostname for security)]

Error: `TEST10_PX host instance on server  could not be created: Exception calling "Install" : "Provided credentials are not valid. Verify logon and password.".Exception.ToString()`

Did anyone come through this error and know how to resolve? ( User has SQL database access, and I can manually assign and start the service)

Expectation is to get the instance configured with username/password provided and start the service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on BizTalk 2020. Problem was a new missing fourth paramter 'IsGmsaAccount' as mentioned in the Github script from Sandro Pereira you mentioned in your question.
The Script in your question is the old one, in case of you also work on BizTalk 2020.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).